# Qt negative button not working

Tags: qt, symbian, qt4.7

In my Qt symbian app, I have over ride the negative exit button with back to come back on main screen and then again over ride it with exit to close the app, my app is working fine on emulator but when I test it on device it shows exit button instead of back, some time it shows back also but if I go to the same page twice then again it start showing exit button, frustrating part is that app is working fine on Qt emulator but not on device. Does somebody knows whats the problem is. I am using

```
back->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::NegativeSoftKey);
this->addAction(back);
```

to over ride the exit button before loading the screen and

```
back->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::NegativeSoftKey);
this->removeAction(back);
```

to removing back button when coming back to mainWindow.

Comment: 4.7 sorry I mistakenly select both

Comment: @talnicolas Do you have any suggestions? I am really stuck at it and need to solve it today only ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create vertical layout and Widget which You will add on scrollarea with parent as that class this e.g

```
QVBoxLayout *vlay = new QVBoxLayout(this); 
QWidget *area = new QWidget(this)
```

And add widget to it
This will make it child of parent class.
works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding and removing `QAction` objects here and there is asking for problems. 
You should try to redesign your application to use a [`QStateMachine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatemachine.html) to handle transitions between states. 
Take a look at the introductory documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [LINK](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Qt_Softkeys) for custom softkeys..

```
QAction* myAction= new QAction(tr("My Action"), this);
myAction->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::NegativeSoftKey);
addAction(myAction);
```

Comment: I am using StackWidget in my app and I am adding multiple widgets in it, to scroll my screen I am using Vertical layout and adding all widgets in it, so there is some problem due to VLayout.